# Occur an error when I use Mono in Spring Webflux framework

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-webflux, objectmapper

I got an error as below.

*class:org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException
ex msg:Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedList[2])*

And requested server got an error also.

*Cannot deserialize value of type `my.study.common.vo.ResultVO` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)*

The reason of above error is response data format that combined JSON String and normal String like this, "[{"key" : "value"}, {"key2" : "value2"}]SERVER_ERROR"

What I wondering is why requested server got response data that concat JSON string with normal String from processing server response despite of occur an error.

```
// Controller.java

@GetMapping
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Object>> list(Data param) {
  DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Object>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(6000L);                

  service.getIds(param, deferredResult); 
  return deferredResult;

}
```

```
// Service.java
@Async 
@Override 
public void getIds(Data param, DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Object>> result) {
  List<Result> results = new LinkedList<>();  
   List<Mono<ResVO>> monoList = new ArrayList<>();

  monoList.add(this.getSomethingByWebclient(param.getName(), specificServerInfo).doOnNext(resVo -> {
    results.add(resVo);
 });

  return Flux.merge(monoList).collectionList().subscribe(r -> {
    result.setResult(new ResponseEntity<>(results, HttpStatus.OK));

  });
}
```

I want to solve that problem or get some hint that can be solve.

Comment: Are you using *Spring MVC* or *Spring Webflux* ? Because your code is mixing MVC `DeferredResult` objects with Webflux *Mono* objects. You should use only one, not both. As *Mono* API is already async, DeferredResult should not be required here. I think you should simplify `getIds` as something like : `public Mono<ResVO> getIds(Data param) { return getSomethingByWebclient(param.getName(), specificServerInfo); }`

Comment: you either use async, or you use webflux, you dont mix the two.

Comment: @amanin Thank you for comment. In fact, I use MVC framework but I heard that WebClient library is good about performance with change RestTemplate to WebClient. So I didn't return by Mono or Flux type instead of using subscribe method. In this case, also can be issued problem?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Please see the above reply 

Comment: If you want to get the most of the webclient, then webflux should be preferred, as it is non-blocking to the core (it uses netty internally to manage requests in a non-blocking fashion). Now, even if you stick to MVC, you should shoose between publisher based code (Mono, Flux) and MVC Async style (@Async, DeferredResult), because they're two different ways to manage async workflow. Now, maybe your Jackson error is not related to that, I couldn't say. The error message tells about an NPE occurring while decoding the third element in your linked list, so maybe check its values.

Comment: @amanin Thank you for comment! I will try to change async style code and will inform you that issues will have been clear!